# How to fix a "WebScarab error 500" with Internet Explorer?

Tags: web-testing, owasp

I am newbie to web scarab and tried to configure a proxy in IE for web scarab. After i configure the proxy in IE. I tried to make same configuration in web scarab using "Get IE setting" button.
After the configuration, my internet is not working(in all browsers) and see some message in message tab -> web scarab as shown below

> 6:23:41 Listener-127.0.0.1:8008-3339(URLFetcher.fetchResponse): Closing connection!
>   16:23:41 Listener-127.0.0.1:8008-3338(URLFetcher.fetchResponse): http://www.google.com:80/ : 500 WebScarab error

What do I have to do to get scarab running?

Answer (score 1):

"Get IE setting" is intended for a clean installation, with no IE changes previously made for WebScarab.

By reconfiguring IE to point to WebScarab, and then importing IE's settings for WebScarab's upstream proxy, you have effectively configured WebScarab to use itself as its upstream proxy connection. This results in a loop, and WebScarab cannot function.

Reset the upstream proxy setting in WebScarab to empty, or to the correct settings for your company's proxy.

Comment: hmm... i am more confused.. so, i did configure the IE in LAN setting by checking the 'use the proxy server' and assigned the ip address as 127.0.0.1 and port as 8888. i did the same config(ip address and port no) to web scarab also(my understanding from your comment this makes loops and webscarab will not work). can you give me some web link to understand better or example might be really good to work...

Comment: Please see my above understanding

Comment: Thanks @Rogan. I faced the same issue and I removed the proxy setting under "Tools -> Proxies" and then I was able to see IE's traffic in WebScarab.